# Trying to check the background color on another sheet to decide if I accept the cell value

Tags: excel-formula, background-color

I am trying to modify a formula that currently works to pull a value from another excel sheet in the same workbook. There are three possible colors for the cell on the sheet being searched (yellow, blue, white). I only want cells that have a white background on the sheet being searched before returning the value. I have not found a way to test for cell background color in a target cell on another tab.
I looked at `Cell("color", reference)` but it only test for font color.  Any help will be appreciated.  Here is the working formula without a test for color.

```
=HLOOKUP(B10,'Savings Tracking'!$A$1:$ADX$1000,(MATCH(C10,'Savings Tracking'!$B$1:$B$1000,0)),FALSE)
```

Now I need to expand this for a color test before returning the value in the cell)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use VBA for this. I assure you this is a pretty simple one though. In your workbook, choose the Developer tab (if it's not visible, then: http://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/how-to-add-developer-tab.html) and select Visual Basic. In the left pane (Project-VBAProject), you'll see your workbook name. Right-click and Insert > Module. In the new module, add the following code:

```
Public Function BackGroundColor(rng As Range)
    BackGroundColor = rng.Interior.Color
End Function
```

Now you'll be able to use `=BackGroundColor(some range)` to return the cell color in long format.